# Где проблема: в утечках памяти или в логике программы?

Tags: c++

Задание звучит так - нужно написать программу, в которую поступает число N, и она считает количество все чисел до N, сумма цифр которых равна сумме цифр N.

На джава я бы выполнил ето задание за 10 минут. Но это СИ++ ((
Я не понимаю почему моя программа не работает. Где то вероятнее всего нужно добавить операторы delete[] (а может delete просто).
При их добавлении у меня программа зависает.

Подскажите, где ошибка? Очень надо сегодня решить(

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;


// Функция определения порядка числа
// Аргументы:
// num - число для определения порядка
// Возвращаемое значение:
// Порядок числа
int Order(int num)
{
  int order = 0;
  while(num){
    num /= 10;
    ++order;
  }
  return order;
}

// Функция перевода положительного целого числа в строку
// Аргументы:
// num - число для перевода
// buffer - массив для записи
// buffer_size - размер строки
// Возвращаемое значение:
// true - если перевод осуществлен успешно
// false - в противном случае
bool ItoA(int num, int* buffer, size_t buffer_size)
{
  int num_order = Order(num);
  if(buffer_size < num_order){
        return false;
    }
  //buffer[num_order] = '\0';

  for(int i = num_order; i > 0; --i){
    buffer[i] = num % 10;
    num /= 10;
  }

  return true;
}

int main()
{
  int num = 0;

  cout << "Enter number: ";
  cin >> num;

  int summOfN = 0;
  int num_order = Order(num);
   cout << "num_order: " << num_order << endl;

  int* mass = new int[num_order];
  if(ItoA(num, mass, num_order)){ // успешен ли перевод его в массив?
        for(int i = 1; i <= num_order; i++ ){
            summOfN += mass[i];
        }
    }

     cout << "summOfN: " << summOfN << endl;


  int counter = 0;
  int res = 0; // сумма его цифр

    for(int i = 1; i <= num; i++ ){
        int num_order = Order(i);
        int* mass = new int[num_order];
            if(ItoA(num, mass, num_order)){ // успешен ли перевод его в массив?
                for(int j = 1; j <= num_order; j++ ){
                    res += mass[j];
                }
            }
        if(res == summOfN){
                cout << "res " << res << endl;
            counter++;
            res = 0;
        }


    }

        cout << counter << endl;
      system("pause");
      return 0;
}
```

Comment: С логикой определенно есть проблемы... Введенное число - int, то есть практически наверняка не более 2^32 в беззнаковом представлении, то есть 9 цифр. С терминирующим нулем - 10 знаков. То есть массив под строковое представление можно задать как char str[10]={0}; ровно один раз и забыть про динамическую память. Функция itoa есть в стандартной библиотеке, вам ее писать не надо. Начните с этого...

Comment: Здесь **вообще не нужно** хранить цифры. Из `Order()` делаете функцию, которая возвращает сумму цифр (очередную цифру получаете операцией `%`, а их порядок для подсчета суммы не важен). Вот, собственно и все (я надеюсь, что далее все очевидно). (В очередной раз увидел, почему куча программ на Java столь неэффективна).

Answer (score 2):

Ваша программа выглядит чересчур сложной для описанного вами задания.

Например, в задании не сказано, что нужно создавать массив, и таковой, действительно, не требуется для решения задания.

Программа может выглядеть следующим образом

```
#include <iostream>

unsigned int digits_sum( unsigned int n )
{
    const unsigned int Base = 10;
    unsigned sum = 0;

    do { sum += n % Base; } while ( n /= Base );

    return sum;
}

int main()
{
    while ( true )
    {
        std::cout << "Enter a non-negative number (0 - exit): ";

        unsigned int n = 0;
        std::cin >> n;

        if ( !n ) break;

        unsigned int sum = digits_sum( n );

        size_t count = 0;
        for ( unsigned int i = 1; i < n; i++ )
        {
            count += sum == digits_sum( i );
        }

        std::cout << "There are " << count 
                  << " numbers less than " << n
                  << " that have the sum of their own digits equal to " << sum
                  << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Если, например, последовательно ввести числа 25, 24, 23, 22, 2, 20, 0, то вывод на консоль может выглядеть как

```
Enter a non-negative number (0 - exit): 25
There are 2 numbers less than 25 that have the sum of their own digits equal to 7
Enter a non-negative number (0 - exit):24
 There are 2 numbers less than 24 that have the sum of their own digits equal to 6
Enter a non-negative number (0 - exit): 23
There are 2 numbers less than 23 that have the sum of their own digits equal to 5
Enter a non-negative number (0 - exit): 22
There are 2 numbers less than 22 that have the sum of their own digits equal to 4
Enter a non-negative number (0 - exit): 21
There are 2 numbers less than 21 that have the sum of their own digits equal to 3
Enter a non-negative number (0 - exit): 20
There are 2 numbers less than 20 that have the sum of their own digits equal to 2
Enter a non-negative number (0 - exit): 0
```

Что касается вашего кода, то уже, к примеру, функция `ItoA` логически и фактически некорректная.

```
bool ItoA(int num, int* buffer, size_t buffer_size)
{
  int num_order = Order(num);
  if(buffer_size < num_order){
        return false;
    }
  //buffer[num_order] = '\0';

  for(int i = num_order; i > 0; --i){
    buffer[i] = num % 10;
    num /= 10;
  }

  return true;
}
```

Логически она некорректная, потому что `buffer_size` может быть указан больше, чем `num_order`, и тогда часть массива будет не заполнена, и непонятно, как определить, то ли массив заполнен полностью, то ли нет и содержит в конце "мусор".

Фактическая ошибка состоит в том, что элемент массива с индексом 0 не заполняется, так как в этом цикле

```
  for(int i = num_order; i > 0; --i){
    buffer[i] = num % 10;
    num /= 10;
  }
```

стоит условие `i > 0`. Поэтому элемент массива с индексом 0 имеет неопределенное значение. И кроме того, вы выходите за границу массива. Например, если `num_order` равно 1, то есть число имеет одну цифру, то в цикле имеет место попытка записать в элемент массива с индексом `num_order` в то время как соответствующий массив создавался как

```
int* mass = new int[num_order];
```

то есть допустимый диапазон индексов `[0, num_order - 1]`

Поэтому программа имеет неопределенное поведение.